# ASP.Net How to kill unused session

Tags: asp.net, session

we can write code by which we can kill session when user click on log out button or click on close button of browser but some time user may go to another site from my site or suddenly browser crash and close and some time power cut so machine close. how to handle this kind of situation and kill session for that particular user. what would be the best strategy for  session management for big portal.i will be glad if any experience developer gude me how to kill unused session and also guide me for best strategy & session management for big portal. thanks

Comment: Sessions time out automatically after 20 minutes of no activity. This amount of time can be configured as well. Do you need more than that? If so, why?

Comment: Either a) don't worry about it because IIS will manage it, or b) if it is becoming a problem, you need to look at what you are putting in the Session. Are you putting large objects in there? If so, you need to look at alternative such as storing the majority of that information in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't worry about these situations and rather let `IIS` handle the session and when it times out.

You can alter this in your `Web.Config` file and change the `<sessionState>` timeout property.

```
<sessionState timeout="10">
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.90).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session.Abandon() method to kill session, but it is very hard way to catch when user leave you site. One of the best way is send client request on document.unload event.

Comment: when document.unload fire when browser close ? am i right. how to detect when user go to another site from my site.

Comment: @Thomas, yes browser fire up document.unload on page close (e.g. tab or window close) or url change (navigate to other page). You can't detect when user simply change active tab to another site or open other browser window and goes to other site.

Comment: @Thomas if you need to detect when user navigates from your site to another you can use window.onunload (not document, my error, sorry). more there [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload)